# Menu with functions

Tags: c, function

I have a question about functions with c language. I have a menu that inserts numbers calling a function but the problem is that i dont want to use a for, i want to insert the numbers one by one every time i press the option a in the menu. I also want to print only the numbers i entered when i select the b option. I just don't know how to fix the counter problem. Sorry if there are grammatical mistakes, english is not my first language.

```
#include<stdio.h>
//Functions
char menu();
void insert (int[],int);
void print (int[],int);

//******************************
//CUERPO
int main (){
    int lenght=5;
    int num [lenght];
    char option;

    while((option=menu())!='x'){

        switch (option){

        case 'a':
            insert(num,largo);
            break;

        case 'b':
            print (num,largo);
            break;
        }
    }
    system ("pause");  
    return 0;
}

/* Codes ************************************************************** */

char menu (){
    char option;
    printf("\nInsert an option :" );
    printf("\nA. insert  :" );
    printf("\nB. print :" );

    scanf("%c", &option);
    fflush (stdin);
    return option;
}

void insert (int a[], int lenght){ // Here i have the problem
    int x=0;  
    printf("\nInsert your number %d: ", x);
    scanf("%d", &a[x]);
    x++;
}

void print (int a[], int lenght){
    int y;
    for(y=0; y<largo; y++){
        printf("\nThe numer you have entered are %d: ", a[y]);
    }
}
```

Comment: which standard are you using c90 or c99?. in insert x is not useful. may be you are missing a loop or is it static? also length is not being used in the insert function? is `largo` supposed to be `length?`

Comment: I'm pretty sure I understand what you're trying to accomplish and where it's going wrong, but it's better not to leave it so ambiguous. Can you please explain what your input is, what you expect the result to be, and what the result actually is?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare on a "x" variable in your main function.

```
int x = 0;
```

Add after the user select the option "insert" the increment of x

```
insert(num,largo);
x++;
```

And finally change you "insert" function to accept "x" and not declare it.

```
void insert (int a[], int lenght, int x){
    printf("\nInsert your number %d: ", x);
    scanf("%d", &a[x]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
//Functions
char menu();
void insert (int[],int);
void print (int[],int);
//******************************
//CUERPO
int main (){
    int lenght=5;
    int num [lenght];
    int largo=-1;
    char option;

    while(tolower((option=menu()))!='x'){

        switch (option){

        case 'a':
            if(largo == 4){
                printf("\nalready full inputted!!\n");
                break;
            }
            insert(num,++largo);
            break;

        case 'b':
            print (num,largo);
            break;
        }
    }
    system ("pause");  
    return 0;
}

/* Codes ************************************************************** */

char menu (){
    char option;
    printf("\nInsert an option :" );
    printf("\nA. insert  :" );
    printf("\nB. print :" );
    printf("\nX. quit. >");

    scanf(" %c", &option);
    while(fgetc(stdin)!='\n');//skip over input
//    fflush (stdin);
    return option;
}

void insert (int a[], int lenght){ // Here i have the problem
    printf("\nInsert your number %d: ", lenght);
    scanf("%d%*c", &a[lenght]);
}

void print (int a[], int lenght){
    printf("\nThe numer you have entered are %d: ", a[lenght]);
}
```